# Trying to make a variable from curl wttr.in output

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl

I want to get the outside temperature into a variable.

```
curl wttr.in/berlin?format=%t
```

produces a perfect clean output of, for example `+8°C` (at command prompt) that I'd like. `%t` is for temperature. however this

```
curl wttr.in/berlin?format=%t>temp.txt
set /p temp=<temp.txt
```

produces `-7┬░C` which I don't like. I just wonder if I could fix this `for` command instead and skip the character set problem

```
for /f %%x in ('curl wttr.in/berlin?format=%t') do set temp=%%x
```

but this one suddenly produces general multirow result instead of just the simple temperature, along with error

```
 Could not resolve host: %t
```

ultimately I will need multiple variables from wttr.in so it would be most efficient to extract them all at once, and set variables accordingly, for example

```
curl wttr.in/berlin?format="%t+%C+%w"
```

where `%C` is conditions, `%w` is wind. does this mean that fixing the `for` loop is the way to go for simplicity?

Comment: In your `For` loop, change `format=%t` to `format^=%%t`. BTW, in your previous code example, `set /p temp=temp.txt` should have read `set /p temp=<temp.txt`.

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"curl wttr.in/berlin?format="%%t+%%C+%%w""') do echo %%a` fixes your `for` problem. No solution for the weird characters though.

Comment: @Compo Hmm, this too returns as `+8┬░C`.

Comment: I wasn't giving you a solution to your encoding problem Bricktop, I was showing you how to correct both of your incorrect commands.

Comment: The problem is, `curl` returns a Unicode string. Writing it to an ASCII file "translates" the two Unicode bytes of `°` into two bytes.

Comment: I honestly don't understand why you'd need to parse the known `°C` part anyhow, surely you only need the number, the rest can be added manually if required in later output.

Comment: @Compo `chcp 65001` command fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chcp 65001
for /f "tokens=1-9,*" %%a in ('"curl wttr.in/berlin?format^="%%t+%%M+%%p+%%D+%%S+%%z+%%s+%%d+%%C""') do (
    set "temperature=%%a"
    set "tempfeel=%%b"
    set "moonday=%%c"
    set "precipitation=%%d"
    set "dawn=%%e"
    set "sunrise=%%f"
    set "zenith=%%g"
    set "sunset=%%h"
    set "dusk=%%i"
    set "condition=%%j"
)
```

`Unicode` fixes the unicode issue, `^` fixes the `for` loop, along with `"tokens=1-9,*"` for collecting all text based variables `"%%t+%%M+%%p+%%D+%%S+%%z+%%s+%%d+%%C"`, where `condition` is a phrase, collected by the `*`.